# How does Visual Studio find Unity/P&P or Office assemblies in its Add References Dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, reference, add-references-dialog

I have read other posts on SO regarding VS's Add References dialog and how it populates assemblies. However, even after looking in *Reference Assemblies* folder and using the *AssemblyFolders* registry key for 32-bit and 64-bit, I am still unable to locate some assemblies, such as Unity/P&P and Office assemblies, when searching for them programmatically. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) to see where the assemblies that are actually used exists on disk.

Comment: Umm, how does this relate to my question? I know exactly where they are on disk by looking at their properties in VS. What I need is finding them programmatically, just like *Add Reference* dialog does.

Comment: As I understod the question you couldn't find the assemblies on disk. Not that you were looking for them with your program.

Comment: Ahh, I see. No, I actually know very well where they are, considering that I can look at the properties for the reference.

Comment: Yes, but in runtime they might not be where you think since a running assembly can be in a cache folder somewhere. Anyway, it was a misreading on my part.